# My battery life dropped from approximetely 20 hours to less than 15 hours, how to find who is responsible?

Tags: battery-life, samsung-galaxy-s-20

My `Samsung Galaxy S20` battery lifetime was up to 20 hours per one charge. The I have probably installed some apps, and the time is dropped to less than 15 hours. The phone is clearly warm during the day. It is definitely doing something. How to know what namely?

[`GSam battery monitor`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gsamlabs.bbm&hl=en&gl=US) told it can't determine power consumption on per application basis.

Can I see processor usage or something?

---

I gave permissions to `GSam` and it showed, that most consumption is from `Android system` itself. Can some application add module to the system, which consumes power?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: What about the built-in battery monitor in Android settings?

Comment: @Robert it is very poor and doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Therefore it is an comment and not an answer. You have enough rep to know how Stackexchange works. But the battery usage monitor included in settings is a system app and therefore has special permissions. No app that you can install have access to that much data like a system app. Therefore my question is more than valid. Ignoring the most valuable source of information is a bad idea. Therefore I was asking.

Comment: Have you looked at similar questions on this site already? From the "related" section: [Android smartphone battery suddenly drained twice as fast than usual](/q/158338/16575); from your tags: our [battery-life tag wiki](/tags/battery-life/info) links quite a lot matches, like [How can I tell what is really draining my battery?](/q/10294/16575) // [How can I monitor the device battery consumption?](/q/28570/16575) // [What can I do to increase battery life on my Android device?](/q/476/16575). Other questions using that tag might hold additional help.

Comment: PS: I'd also check network stats. Some of your new apps might be busy even when you're not using them. Especially on Play Store, most of the apps are pretty "stuffed" with ad libraries and such (one of the reasons I prefer getting mine from F-Droid).

Comment: @Izzy multiplicity of answers proves that there is no (final) answer. The question is simple: something is eating my power. How to pinpoint it?

Comment: Dims, the multiplicity of answers gives you different approaches to find out. Those answers have already been given, which is why we link to them instead of repeating them. Only the person with the device in hand can tell which one it is. Going by the 3rd screenshot I'd say something urgently wants to sync something and gets stuck in a loop, keeping the device awake. But what it is would probably require logcat to look at. You could just disable account sync and see if that has an effect, then if so, try those syncs one by one until you found the culprit.